# Python - Replace missing values with mean

Tags: python, scikit-learn, missing-data

As a beginner I'm doing a python course. In this course they use a dataset [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaNZA.jpg) with resp. the column names: "Country", "Age", "Salary" and "Purchased". 
In the 2nd and 3rd column (Age and Salary) are a few missing values. For Python starts counting the columns with 0, I would expect the following code does the job:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer 
imputer = Imputer(missing_values="NaN",strategy="mean", axis=0)
imputer=imputer.fit(X[:,1:2]) 
X[:,1:2] =imputer.transform(X[:,1:2])
```

However, in this course they say that we need to use everywhere X[:,1:3] and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that slicing using `[start:stop]` takes the elements from `start` to `stop-1`, so

```
[0,1,2,3,4][1:2]
```

returns

```
[1]
```

So if you want the second and third element, try

```
[0,1,2,3,4][1:3]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Florian. It's confusing, but it explains it. I will take this rule into account when I need it after the course. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah this way of counting in Python is stupid. I constantly get tripped up by it.